# scale_x_discrete not showing data some data and hiding another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a graph showing data by fiscal year. The problem I have is that **ggplot is showing a point that does not exist in the data frame containing the information, and not painting another that really exists**. Could you please masters of ggplot help me? Thank you very much!!

The code is:

```
    plot = ggplot(data = headcountPerMonth,
              aes(x = Month.Number, 
                  y = Headcount, 
                  group = Fiscal.Year, 
                  colour = Fiscal.Year)) +
       geom_line() +    
       geom_point() +  
       labs(colour = "Fiscal year") +
       scale_x_discrete(
         name = "Month", 
         labels = headcountPerMonth$Month.Name
       ) +
       scale_y_continuous(name = "Headcount");
    print(plot);
```

The plot is the next one. As you can see there is **a value Month = March, Fiscal.Year = 2012, but not on Month = June, Fiscal.Year = 2012**.

[image]

The data from the plot is the next one. As you can see **there is no value Month = March, Fiscal.Year = 2012, but exists on Month = June, Fiscal.Year = 2012**.

```
        Month Headcount Fiscal.Year Month.Number Month.Name
1  2010-04-01        48        2010            4        abr
2  2010-05-01        49        2010            5        may
3  2010-06-01        52        2010            6        jun
4  2010-07-01        51        2010            7        jul
5  2010-08-01        51        2010            8        ago
6  2010-09-01        51        2010            9        sep
7  2010-10-01        52        2010           10        oct
8  2010-11-01        54        2010           11        nov
9  2010-12-01        54        2010           12        dic
10 2011-01-01        56        2010            1        ene
11 2011-02-01        56        2010            2        feb
12 2011-03-01        61        2010            3        mar
13 2011-04-01        61        2011            4        abr
14 2011-05-01        59        2011            5        may
15 2011-06-01        59        2011            6        jun
16 2011-07-01        61        2011            7        jul
17 2011-08-01        59        2011            8        ago
18 2011-09-01        58        2011            9        sep
19 2011-10-01        59        2011           10        oct
20 2011-11-01        65        2011           11        nov
21 2011-12-01        68        2011           12        dic
22 2012-01-01        72        2011            1        ene
23 2012-02-01        72        2011            2        feb
24 2012-03-01        72        2011            3        mar
25 2012-04-01        77        2012            4        abr
26 2012-05-01        77        2012            5        may
27 2012-06-01        80        2012            6        jun
28 2012-07-01        80        2012            7        jul
29 2012-08-01        77        2012            8        ago
30 2012-09-01        81        2012            9        sep
31 2012-10-01        86        2012           10        oct
32 2012-11-01        86        2012           11        nov
33 2012-12-01        85        2012           12        dic
34 2013-01-01        88        2012            1        ene
35 2013-02-01        86        2012            2        feb
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem arise due to fact that variable `Month.Number` in your data is numeric. When you use in `ggplot()` values are plotted from `1:12`, not from `4:12` and `1:3` as you expect.

To solve the problem you can convert `Month.Number` to factor with levels in expected order (it can be done also inside `aes()` with function `factor()`).

```
ggplot(data = headcountPerMonth,
       aes(x = factor(Month.Number,levels=c(4:12,1,2,3)), 
           y = Headcount, group = Fiscal.Year, 
           colour = as.factor(Fiscal.Year))) +
  geom_line() +    
  geom_point() +  
  labs(colour = "Fiscal year") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Headcount")+
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Month", labels = headcountPerMonth$Month.Name)
```