# ggplot2 bar plot does not display labels as defined in scale_x_discrete()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

My dataset is the following:

```
 Index  Feature scaled_Gain sign_Correlation
    1   a   1.00000000  1
    2   b   0.60999674  1
    3   c   0.54824913  1
    4   d   0.11134079  1
    5   e   0.06530486  1
    6   f   0.06470836  1
    7   g   0.06263247  1
    8   h   0.04166633  1
    9   i   0.03242897  -1
    10  j   0.02913138  1
```

My code is the following:

```
ggplot(data = plot_data) +
geom_bar(aes(x = Index, y = scaled_Gain, fill = sign_Correlation), stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) + 
theme_economist() + ggtitle("Scaled Gain")  + scale_x_discrete(labels = plot_data$Feature)
```

The plot is the following:

[image]

My question is: Why the labels do not appear in the x-axis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scale\_x\_discrete not showing data some data and hiding another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465141/scale-x-discrete-not-showing-data-some-data-and-hiding-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Feature, scaled_Gain, fill = factor(sign_Correlation))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.5) + 
  ggtitle("Scaled Gain") + 
  labs(fill = "Sign Correlation") +
  ggthemes::theme_economist()
```

[image]

I think the only problem here is that you're using `aes(Index, scaled_Gain)` instead of `aes(Feature, scaled_Gain)`.